# how to embed c++ code using ironpython?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, embed, ironpython

1. how to embed c++ code using ironpython?

"#include "
says error, because in folder c:\ironpython27 doesn't have include folder (*.h files).

2. can we embed ironpython into C++? or IronPython is only meant for C#?

environment: win 7, VS 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iron python is actually written in C# and meant to extend DOT NET e.g. C# & VB seamlessly. Hence, to work embed in C++, it'd better to use standard python.

https://www.infoworld.com/article/3096748/open-source-tools/python-for-net-rises-from-the-dead.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython

[Iron Python : what are good uses for Iron Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336228/iron-python-what-are-good-uses-for-iron-python)